# Is there a preferable way to create type aliases for compound types with Python's typing module?

Tags: python, typing, typechecking

I have a function with one parameter, which should take an `int` or a `None` as argument. There are several ways to create a type alias for such a compound type:

```
# test.py
import typing

IntOrNone_1 = typing.TypeVar('IntOrNone_1', int, None)
IntOrNone_2 = typing.Union[int, None]


def my_func1(xyz: IntOrNone_1):
    return xyz

def my_func2(xyz: IntOrNone_2):
    return xyz


my_func1(12)
my_func1(None)
my_func1(13.7)
my_func1('str')

my_func2(12)
my_func2(None)
my_func2(13.7)
my_func2('str')
```

Both methods do what I expect them to do, however, the correspondig `mypy` erros differ slightly, but basically have the same meaning.

> test.py:14: error: Value of type variable "IntOrNone_1" of "my_func1"
>   cannot be "float"
>
> test.py:15: error: Value of type variable "IntOrNone_1" of "my_func1"
>   cannot be "str"
>
> test.py:19: error: Argument 1 to "my_func2" has incompatible type
>   "float"; expected "Optional[int]"
>
> test.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "my_func2" has incompatible type
>   "str"; expected "Optional[int]"

I tend to use the second approach, since it additionally reports which argument caused the error.

Are both methods indeed equivalent, as I suppose, or is one of them to be preferred?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a constrained TypeVar and a Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903906/whats-the-difference-between-a-constrained-typevar-and-a-union)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The two methods are very far from being equivalent. You should avoid thinking of TypeVars as being mere aliases -- rather, they're more special forms that you use when you want to make your functions *generic*.

It's easiest to explain what a "generic function" is with an example. Suppose you want to write a function that accepts some object (any object!) and return another object of the *exact same type*. How would you do this?

One method we could do is to try using `object`:

```
def identity(x: object) -> object:
    return x
```

This gets us close, since our `identity` function can at least accept literally anything (since all types inherit from `object` in Python). However, this solution is flawed: if we pass in an int, we get back out `object`, which isn't what we want.

Rather, what we need is a way for the type checker to understand that there's a "relationship" between these two types. This is exactly where `TypeVar` comes in handy:

```
T = TypeVar('T')

def identity(x: T) -> T:
    return x
```

Our TypeVar 'T' in this case is acting as a "placeholder" that can be bound to any type we want. So if we do `identity(3)`, the `T` will be *bound* to `int` -- so the type checker will therefore understand the return type must also be `int`!

And if we use `T` multiple times within our parameter type hints, the type checker will make sure that the types are the same each time.

---

So, what is the expression below doing?

```
IntOrNone_1 = typing.TypeVar('IntOrNone_1', int, None)
```

Well, it turns out that it can sometimes be useful to add *constraints* to our special placeholder type. For example, you've constrained `IntOrNone_1` so that it can be bound to only `int` or `None`, and no other types.

---

And finally, to answer your last question: in the examples you've given, you should absolutely be using Union, not TypeVars.

Whether you use a Union or a type alias to a Union is really a matter of personal taste, but if you don't need this "placeholder" or "generic" behavior, you shouldn't be using TypeVars.

The mypy docs has a [section on generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html) if you'd like to learn more about how to use TypeVars. It covers several things I skipped, including how to make generic classes (not just generic functions).