# What's the difference between a constrained TypeVar and a Union?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, union-types, type-variables

If I want to have a type that can be multiple possible types, `Union`s seem to be how I represent that:

```
U = Union[int, str]
```

`U` can be an `int` or a `str`.

I noticed though that `TypeVar`s allow for optional var-arg arguments that also seem to do the same thing:

```
T = TypeVar("T", int, str)
```

Both `T` and `U` seem to only be allowed to take on the types `str` and `int`.

What are the differences between these two ways, and when should each be preferred?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there ar preferable way to create type aliases for compound types with Python's typing module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336690/is-there-ar-preferable-way-to-create-type-aliases-for-compound-types-with-python)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`T`'s type must be consistent across multiple uses within a given [scope](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#scoping-rules-for-type-variables), while `U`'s does not.

With a `Union` type used as function parameters, the arguments as well as the return type can all be different:

```
U = Union[int, str]

def union_f(arg1: U, arg2: U) -> U:
    return arg1

x = union_f(1, "b")  # No error due to different types
x = union_f(1, 2)  # Also no error
x = union_f("a", 2)  # Also no error
x # And it can't tell in any of the cases if 'x' is an int or string
```

Compare that to a similar case with a `TypeVar` where the argument types must match:

```
T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

def typevar_f(arg1: T, arg2: T) -> T:
    return arg1

y = typevar_f(1, "b")  # "Expected type 'int' (matched generic type 'T'), got 'str' instead
y = typevar_f("a", 2)  # "Expected type 'str' (matched generic type 'T'), got 'int' instead

y = typevar_f("a", "b")  # No error
y  # It knows that 'y' is a string

y = typevar_f(1, 2)  # No error
y  # It knows that 'y' is an int
```

So, use a `TypeVar` if multiple types are allowed, but different usages of `T` within a single scope must match each other. Use a `Union` if multiple types are allowed, but different usages of `U` within a given scope don't need to match each other.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on the meaning of "within a single scope" in this context? Specifically, if I'm an "outer scope" (a module or a class or whatever) and I declare a TypeVar, and I use that type in two different functions, do usages of the var have to match withing the two inner scopes (functions) separately, or across the whole outer scope? What if I have nested functions?

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter Note the part of the PEP that I linked to at the top. It goes into quite in-depth detail.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter If `T` is defined outside of any functions though, its type can vary across functions, unless those functions are methods, and the class that encloses them is `Generic` on `T`.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add, as a consequence of what @Carcigenicate explained:

With `Union`, the operation you use between arguments has to be supported by all arguments *in any permutation order*:

```py
from typing import Union

U = Union[int, str]

def add(a: U, b: U):
    return a + b
```

Here `int + int` and `str + str` is OK but not the `int + str` and `str + int`.
Mypy says:

```
main.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
main.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
```

If we change `+` to `*`: `int * str` and `str * int` and `int * int` is OK but Mypy doesn't like `str * str`:

```py
from typing import Union

U = Union[int, str]

def add(a: U, b: U):
    return a * b
```

Mypy says:

```
main.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for * ("str" and "str")
```

If we change `U = Union[int, str]` to `U = Union[int, float]` with above tests, it accepts. All four cases are acceptable.

Here we use `TypeVar` instead to get rid of those complains, the `T` is the same, either `int + int` or `str + str`:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

def add(a: T, b: T) -> T:
    return a + b
```