# Python mypy checking of return types for TypeVar(bound=Union[A, B]) doesn't error vs TypeVar(A, B) does error

Tags: python, generics, static-analysis, mypy

I am stuck trying to understand bounding of `TypeVar` when using it in two different ways:

- `Enums = TypeVar("Enums", Enum1, Enum2)`
- `Enums = TypeVar("Enums", bound=Union[Enum1, Enum2])`

Here is the code I am using:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

"""Figuring out why enum is saying incompatible return type."""


from enum import IntEnum, EnumMeta
from typing import TypeVar, Union


class Enum1(IntEnum):

    MEMBER1 = 1
    MEMBER2 = 2


class Enum2(IntEnum):

    MEMBER3 = 3
    MEMBER4 = 4


# Enums = TypeVar("Enums", bound=Union[Enum1, Enum2])  # Case 1... Success
Enums = TypeVar("Enums", Enum1, Enum2)  # Case 2... error: Incompatible return value


def _enum_to_num(val: int, cast_enum: EnumMeta) -> Enums:
    return cast_enum(val)


def get_some_enum(val: int) -> Enum1:
    return _enum_to_num(val, Enum1)


def get_another_enum(val: int) -> Enum2:
    return _enum_to_num(val, Enum2)  # line 35
```

When running `mypy==0.770`:

- `Case 1`: `Success: no issues found`
- `Case 2`: `35: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Enum1", expected "Enum2")`

This case is *very* similar to this question: [Difference between TypeVar('T', A, B) and TypeVar('T', bound=Union[A, B])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933946/difference-between-typevart-a-b-and-typevart-bound-uniona-b)

The answer explains when using case 1(`bound=Union[Enum1, Enum2]`), the following is legal:

1. `Union[Enum1, Enum2]`
2. `Enum1`
3. `Enum2`

And when using case 2 (`A, B`), the following is legal:

1. `Enum1`
2. `Enum2`

---

However, I don't think this answer explains my problem, I am not using the `Union` case.

Can anyone please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error occurs because the type checker does not have enough information to *infer* the return type by looking at the types of input arguments. Although the handling may be improved.

Suppose you have a simple generic function:

```
Enums = TypeVar("Enums", Enum1, Enum2)

def add(x: Enums, y: Enums) -> Enums:
    return x
```

The type checker can infer the return type by *type of input arguments*:

```
add(Enum2.MEMBER3, Enum2.MEMBER4) # ok, return Enum2
add(Enum1.MEMBER1, Enum1.MEMBER2) # ok, return Enum1

add(Enum2.MEMBER3, Enum1.MEMBER2) # not ok
```

Look at your function `_enum_to_num` again, the type checker has no means to infer the return type, it just doesn't know what type will be returned because it doesn't know what type will be returned by `cast_enum`:

```
def _enum_to_num(val: int, cast_enum: EnumMeta) -> Enums:
    return cast_enum(val)
```

The idea of static type checking is that it evaluates the code without execution, it investigates the *types* of variables, not the dynamic *values*. By looking at the type of `cast_enum`, that is `EnumMeta`, the type checker cannot tell whether `cast_enum` will return `Enums` or not. Looks like it just assumes it will return `Enum1`, and it causes the error in `_enum_to_num(val, Enum2)`.

You know that `_enum_to_num(val, Enum2)` will return `Enum2` because you know the *value* of `cast_enum` is `Enum2`. The *value* is something that *type* checker doesn't touch in general. It may be confusing, the *value* of the variable `cast_enum` is `Enum2`, while the *type* of `cast_enum` is `EnumMeta`, although `Enum2` is a *type*.

This issue can be solved by telling the type checker that types will be passed through `cast_enum` using [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, Type

...

def _enum_to_num(val: int, cast_enum: Type[Enums]) -> Enums:
    return cast_enum(val)
```

The error will disappear because now the type checker can infer the return type.

Comment: While I agree with most of this, I don't think this is totally accurate given what we see: there is no type error reported by mypy for `get_some_enum()` and that's because it has decided that the `Enums` type is the same thing as the first item on the list of types. One could imagine that it keep a list of all of the types listed and check for subclasses in all of those like it does for the Union type. So the question then becomes is this intentional or accidental?

Comment: @rocky I think the issue is that mypy inferred the return type of `_enum_to_num()` as the first type in `Enums`, such that there is no error for `get_some_enum()`. But this behavior sounds wired to me, instead of picking the first type, I would prefer mypy warning the user in `_enum_to_num()` that it cannot infer the return type.

Comment: Thank you @KenHung, that indeed explain where I was going wrong with `EnumMeta` type hint, and I am now able to get `mypy` saying `Success: no issues found`.

Comment: Yes @rocky I agree with your statement "it has decided that the `Enums` type is the same thing as the first item on the list of types". If anything, I think `mypy` should have warned something about `EnumMeta` not necessarily leading to an `Enums` type.  I think this may not be a bug, but more of an edge case that has yet to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I write first a little about what mypy sees and reports, and follow with the question of whether this is a mypy bug.

The message:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Enum1", expected "Enum2")
```

means here that roughly that a `Enum2` or a subtype of that is expected. `Enum2` is the declared return value of `get_another_enum()`. However mypy thinks that the function call `_enum_to_num()` is returning an `Enum1` type.

The "roughly" part is because there are exceptions for type checking when a type is unbound, or is an `Any`, or `Union` type; but that doesn't apply in this example.

Mypy decides that the function `cast_enum()` in `_enum_to_num()` is returning the *first* type listed in `Enums` — I guess as a static type checker, it has to pick one and that's what it does.

So if you switch the order around in the `Enums` assignment and write:

```
Enums = TypeVar("Enums", Enum2, Enum1)  # Case 2... error: Incompatible return value
```

Then line 35 will succeed, but the return in `get_some_enum()` will fail with the message:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Enum2", expected "Enum1")
```

As to whether this is a mypy bug, it is hard to tell...

There is no dynamic type error that you can find here using the `type()` or `ininstance()` functions; *running* the code works as expected too.

On the other hand, Python never checks the return type whether at compile time or at run time: you could change the return type of `_enum_to_none()` to be `None` and that would still be valid as far as the Python interpreter is concerned.

The question then comes down to: in the static type system imposed by mypy, is this a bug? (I don't think PEP 484, 526, or other numbers try to address this).

Someone more qualified should answer the question of whether this is a bug that should be caught by a static analyzer, mypy in particular.

See Ken Hung's answer for a way to be more explicit and remove mypy's error.

Comment: Thank you @rocky, this explains what is happening, and I guess it answers my question of `Can anyone please tell me what's going on?`.  However, it doesn't explain why `mypy` has a problem with this.  This seems to be a bug in `mypy`, would you agree?  In other words, I still think `mypy` should not raise an error with `Case 2`.

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer I've revised the answer to _start_ to address the question of whether this is a mypy bug.

Comment: Thanks for editing/improving @rocky, and also I updated the question's wording based on your suggestion.  I wish I could split the bounty in two.

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer I am not concerned about the points. Am glad that the problem has been solved.