# what does argument "bound" mean in typing.TypeVar?

Tags: python, typing

So I am trying to learn typing module and I am completely stuck on `bound=` part.
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933946/difference-between-typevart-a-b-and-typevart-bound-uniona-b) comprehensive topic a couple a times, but since I am newbie to this I didn't understand much.

Can you please explain what `bound=` is for and what does upper-bound means? (on a simple example preferably)

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) is a bit cryptic about this subject, especially if you are a beginner. Lets take the following example:

```
class Foo:
    pass


class Bar(Foo):
    pass


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Foo)  # Can be any subtype of Foo


def foo_bar(x: T):
    print(x)


foo_bar(Bar()) # valid
```

Here the `bound` parameter means that any instance of class that inherits `Foo`, or any of its subclasses validates the typing criteria defined with `T`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! But in this case, why wouldn't we just use ``Foo`` as typehint directly? Meaning `foo_bar(x: Foo)`.

Comment: @cryoris: You can, but that doesn't work if you want to return an object related to `T`. Say you perform some mutable changes, then return the instance back. You would be forced to type-hint the return as `Foo`, but the caller probably requires `Bar` on occasion. Type hinting a return of `T` solves this.