# Type Aliases in Python

Tags: python, typescript, alias, typing

In TypeScript I can write something like:

```js
function foo<T>(a: T): T{
}

function foo<T extends A>(a: T): T{
}
```

And TypeScript will know that if I call `let myVar = foo(1)`, `myVar` will be a number

How can I achieve the same result in Python?

Basically, I'm using `prometheus-client`, and I want to create a utility function that allows you to register a `Metric` of any type.
The function should then return the metric, of the same type.

So if I call

```py
def register_metric(metric: Metric) -> Metric


my_summary = register_metric(Summary("some_summary", "summary description"))

my_counter = register_metric(Counter("some_counter", "counter description"))
```

then `my_summary` will be a `Summary` and my IDE will know that I have the `.observe` method
while `my_counter` will be a `Counter` with the `.inc` method

EDIT: I noticed the [typing Generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) which allows me to create a `T` variable.
I can't seem to figure out how to limit it to only sub-classes of `Metric`, similar to how in TypeScript I can do `<T extends A>`

Comment: [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)?

Comment: It could work, but it's not very elegant. I was hoping for something like TypeScript does it

Comment: Check [Generics/templates in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6725868/10824407).

Comment: How can I restrict the type though? I want it to just accept `Metric` and it's child classes

Comment: Check [Subclass in type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46092104/10824407). I highly recommend you to use search box at the top.

Comment: Take a look at [what does argument "bound" mean in typing.TypeVar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244928/what-does-argument-bound-mean-in-typing-typevar).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class hierarchy like this

```
class Metric:
    pass


class Summary(Metric):
    pass


class Counter(Metric):
    pass
```

You can define a `TypeVar` with `bound=Metric`, indicating that the `TypeVar` must be a type that "an actual type substituted (explicitly or implicitly) for the type variable must be a subclass of the boundary type" ([TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)).

```
from typing import TypeVar

MetricT = TypeVar("MetricT", bound=Metric)
```

Then you can use `MetricT` to define `register_metric`:

```
def register_metric(metric: MetricT) -> MetricT:
    return metric


summary = register_metric(Summary())
counter = register_metric(Counter())
```

Result:

```
reveal_type(summary)  # Type of "summary" is "Summary"
reveal_type(counter)  # Type of "summary" is "Counter"
```