# Why do I get mypy errors when comparing values of type ` TypeVar('T', bound=int|float)`?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I get unexpected `mypy` errors when using builtin binary operations on variables of type `TypeVar('T', bound=int|float)`.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound=typing.Union[int, float])

def less_than(x: T, y: T) -> bool:
    return x < y
```

`mypy` gives me the following error:

```
test.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for < ("int" and "T")
```

Why do I get that error?

On a side note: `mypy` doesn't complain if I use `T = typing.Union[int, float]` or `T = typing.TypeVar('T', int, float)`.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12800.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/_operator.pyi, `__lt__` is typed using a union of protocols, which themselves are all typed with `Any`. My theory is that `Any` does *not* include `Union[int, float]`, only concrete types, and using `Union` as an upper bound on a type hint (rather than a type hint itself) prevents `mypy` from "realizing" `T` as a concrete type.

Comment: (All of which is to say, it *feels* like an upper bound of `Union` is too vague, but I can't really articulate why it should or should not work. I'm looking forward to a good answer for this question.)

Comment: also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/59933946/5986907