# Why does mypy fail on this automatically annotated module by MonkeyType?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-analysis, mypy

Assume the following module and script file:

`mymodule.py`

```py
# Module to be annotated by MonkeyType
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

`myscript.py`

```py
from mymodule import add

add(2, 3)
add('x', 'y')
```

Automatically annotate the module with the [MonkeyType](https://pypi.org/project/MonkeyType/) module using the Ubuntu terminal.

```
$ monkeytype run myscript.py
$ monkeytype apply mymodule
```

`mymodule.py` is now altered with the added annotations.

```py
# Module annotated by monkeytype
from typing import Union

def add(a: Union[int, str], b: Union[int, str]) -> Union[int, str]:
    return a + b
```

But if I run [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html), the static type checker, the execution terminates with 2 errors.
Why does this occur?

```
$ mypy mymodule.py
mymodule.py:4: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
mymodule.py:4: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
mymodule.py:4: note: Both left and right operands are unions
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

btw I use <s>arch</s> Python 3.8.

Comment: You need `TypeVar` instead of `Union`. See here: [What's the difference between a constrained TypeVar and a Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58903907/7851470)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the type annotations MonkeyType will produce are necessarily correct: deducing types using runtime information is a technique that has multiple fundamental limitations.

To quote the readme:

> MonkeyType’s annotations are an informative first draft, to be checked and corrected by a developer.

In this particular case, the types are incorrect because the type signature implies doing `add("foo", 3)` is fine even though that will end up causing a crash at runtime: you can't add strings and ints together.