# How to type hint function accepting both union and any type of that union?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

```
$ cat foo.py

from typing import overload, Union, TypeVar

T = Union[int, str]
SubT = TypeVar("SubT", int, str)

@overload
def a(t: T) -> T:
    ...

@overload
def a(t: SubT) -> SubT:
    ...

def a(t: T) -> T:
    return t
```

```
$ mypy foo.py

foo.py:7: error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types
```

Why are the return types incompatible, and how can I make this typecheck? I want these example return types:

```
v_1: Union[int, str] = 1
v_2: int = 2
v_3: str = "3"

a(v_1)  # Want Union[int, str].
a(v_2)  # Want int.
a(v_3)  # Want str.
```

I want to avoid having to explicitly overload `a` for `int` and `str`, as `SubT` has many more than 2 constraints in reality.

If I remove the first overload, `a(v_1)` wouldn't type check. If I remove the second overload, `a(v_2)` and `a(v_3)` would have their return value type hinted as `Union[int, str]` instead of `int` and `str` respectively.

In my actual problem, I have an `Iterable` of either homogeneous types under `SubT` (the `TypeVar`) or heterogeneous types under `T` (the `Union`). I want to write an `a` that will operate on the elements of both without losing type granulariy if it present in the homogeneous case.

Comment: 'any type of that union' IS the Union (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)  ?

Comment: A union and a typevar are similar. The difference is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903906/whats-the-difference-between-a-constrained-typevar-and-a-union you very likely don't need two types and removing one would simplify your problem.

Comment: @CyrilJouve Yes, but if I operated solely on `Union` then I would lose type granularity if I know what specific type of the union `t` is. See edit.

Comment: @NathanielTracy-Amoroso Reason I think I need both is because I want to be able to support granular type checking (`TypeVar`) while at the same type supporting the broad type (`Union`). See edit.

Comment: Does `TypeVar("SubT", int, str, Union[int, str])` work in your case? (I’m not even sure if it works at all, but…)

Comment: @Ry- That'd do exactly what I want, but unfortunately `TypeVar` constraints cannot be parameterized :(

Comment: @MarioIshac: Hm, what’s the error message in that case? It seems to be working for me: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=06ad95655da139afd80985b02b53ba1e

Comment: @Ry- You're right, I was mixing up your example with `TypeVar("SubT", int, str, X[int, str])` where `X` is a generic class. This wouldn't work, but `Union` is a typing construct not a class. Feel free to copy your earlier comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Possibly relevant discussion of [mypy overload handling](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#type-checking-the-variants) and of the meaning of the [overload decorator](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/253).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeVar` will let you offer both the types of the union and the union itself as options:

```py
T = TypeVar("T", int, str, Union[int, str])

def a(t: T) -> T:
    return t
```

Comment: Hmm, would even `TypeVar("T", bound=Union[int, str])` work? I'm not sure if it's exactly equivalent, but looks like it worked when I tinkered with your mypy gist.

Comment: @MarioIshac: Yeah, I think so! It does mean something slightly different (e.g. with `int` you’ll also get `bool -> bool`, as far as builtins go), but that might be okay or even what you prefer.