# Is it possible to use Python's constrained TypeVar to make subclasses incompatible?

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

According to the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903906/whats-the-difference-between-a-constrained-typevar-and-a-union), constrained `TypeVar`s should **match exactly**.

However, when using custom classes, the behaviour seems counterintuitive:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

@dataclass
class PrinterConnection:
    name: str = ""


@dataclass
class WiFiPrinterConnection(PrinterConnection):
    name = "WiFi"


@dataclass
class USBPrinterConnection(PrinterConnection):
    name = "USB"


@dataclass
class USBTypeCPrinterConnection(USBPrinterConnection):
    name = "USB-C"


Connection = TypeVar("Connection", USBPrinterConnection, WiFiPrinterConnection)

@dataclass
class Printer(Generic[Connection]):
    connection: Connection

Printer(WiFiPrinterConnection())      # No Warning - As Expected
Printer(USBPrinterConnection())       # No Warning - As Expected
Printer(USBTypeCPrinterConnection())  # No Warning - NOT Expected
```

In this example, `USBTypeCPrinterConnection` is not one of the types defined in the the `TypeVar` and yet no warning is thrown.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't a Warning being thrown here?
2. Is there a way to allow for particular classes and not its subclasses?

These examples were done with Python 3.10 and Pylance for the type checking.

Answer (score 0):

A constrained `TypeVar` must **resolve** to one of the specified types, and a subclass can resolve to its parent.

consider

```py
from typing import TypeVar

class Parent:
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass

T = TypeVar("T", Parent, int)  # We need at least two arguments
def foo(x: T) -> T: return x

reveal_type(foo(Child()))  # Parent
```

[Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=dd7dfe3e921f69906c540c547ea4e254)

as you can see even tho we passed a `Child` the type var was **resolved** to a `Parent`.